# Finding the squares of numbers in a .txt

Tags: python, file, gedit

Please, I want to find the squares of the numbers stored in the .txt file named 'myNumbers.txt'

myNumbers.txt

```
2
3
4
5
3
```

I have these python script:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
     f_in=open("myNumbers.txt", "r")     
     for line in f_in:                  
          line=line.rstrip()
          print float(line)**2

     f_in.close()
```

I tried this and it is working very well, but I want to know if there is an other way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always use the `with statement` for handling files. And no there's need to use `str.strip` here, as `float` will take care of the white-spaces:

```
with open("mynumbers.txt") as f_in:
    for line in f_in:                  
        print float(line)**2
```

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects):

> It is good practice to use the **with** keyword when dealing with file
>   objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after
>   its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way.

`float` with white-spaces:

```
>>> float('1.2\n')
1.2
>>> float('  1.2  \n')
1.2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[float(a)**2 for a in open("C:/Users/vjaiswa5/Downloads/a.txt", "r").read().split()]
```

Returns an array of squared numbers.

Comment: Jaiswal, is the 'a' supposed to be the name of the file name excluding the extension or it could be any other variable?

Comment: float(a)**2 for a in open("mynumbers_1.txt", "r").read().split()]
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: there's syntax error in your code, you forgot to add "[". It should be, [float(a)**2 for a in open("mynumbers_1.txt", "r").read().split()]